Postfix mailserver with two IPs. Map each sending IP to different application
I have one mail server (Debian 12, Postfix) with two public IPv4 IPs for two applications.
I must send all emails from application A from IP 1.2.3.4 and application B from IP 5.6.7.8.
Both application servers have local postfix with relay to my mail server.
How can I do that easily?
I have both IPs defined in master.cf:
127.0.0.1:25 inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtp_bind_address=1.2.3.4
    -o smtp_helo_name=mail1.test.net
    -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

127.0.0.1:2525 inet n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtp_bind_address=5.6.7.8
    -o smtp_helo_name=mail2.test.net
    -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

but I don't have idea how to solve mapping app-IP.
I tried to use different ports (25 and 2525) - without success.
Second try was with linux users - without success too.
I tried mapping headers:
# main.cf:
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

# /etc/postfix/header_checks:
/^X-Postfix-Transport: my_transport1/ FILTER smtp:[127.0.0.1]:25
/^X-Postfix-Transport: my_transport2/ FILTER smtp:[127.0.0.1]:2525

but I had no succcess.
I don't need any login, virtual users, ... I have both application servers addresses in mynetworks as security/limit.
What I'm really in need of is a straightforward solution to map app-sending IP.

/etc/postfix/main.cf:
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport_maps

/etc/postfix/sender_transport_maps:
test.a@example.cz ip10:
test.b@example.cz ip20:

/etc/postfix/master.cf:
smtp unix - - n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.2.3.4     -o smtp_helo_name=mail.test.net
ip10 unix - - n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=10.20.30.40 -o smtp_helo_name=mail10.test.net
ip20 unix - - n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=20.30.40.50 -o smtp_helo_name=mail20.test.net

postmap /etc/postfix/sender_transport_maps
systemctl restart postfix.service

Thanks for help https://serverfault.com/a/1163954/217975 @stina-andersson

This is solved by using sender_dependent_default_transport_maps`
1- Backup the config file, it wouldn't be the first time I'm wrong about something!
Edit main.cf:
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport

Create /etc/postfix/sender_transport:
appA@example.com smtp:[127.0.0.1]:25
appB@example.com smtp:[127.0.0.1]:2525

Run:
postmap /etc/postfix/sender_transport
systemctl reload postfix

This directs emails from appA to use IP 1.2.3.4 and appB to use IP 5.6.7.8.

Thank you, I'll try it. appA@example.com is From address? Or user login?

The appA@example.com in this context is the "From" address (the sender’s email address). It’s used to determine which transport (and thus which IP) to use when sending emails. Adjust the sender_transport file to match the "From" addresses of your applications.
